# FindOne NODEJS mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this code that check for me if the token provided is valid or not, the code is working but the problem that it is returning wrong id, => it returns the first Id that he found in the database

the code that I'm using is this

```
const checkToken = async (req, res ,next) => {
    const token= req.body.token //the token is mix of number and letters lenght (6)

    User.findOne(token, 
        (err, user)  => {
            if (err) {
                const error = new Error('Token not Found');
                error.status= 406;
                return next(err, error);
    
           }else
            {
            res.send('/api/users/'+ user.id +'/update') // u need to mention user.id from DB
          
            }       

})
```

this is my image of the database :

[image]

I don't want to use the id to search the token , what I want is use the provided token and search in DB if it is found so I retrieve Id

Answer (score 0):

According to MongoDB documentation that is the usual behavior of findOne method. When multiple documents satisfy the condition the function returns the first document that is written first. [Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/)

To check use find() and see all the documents it returns for the correct id and to use findOne make sure the token is unique for all the document.

Comment: thank you for your answer but here in my case I don't have multiple data that satisfy the condition which mean equal to the value of `token`, it is returning wrong `id` and that `id` got different `token`

Comment: Okay you can try, findOne({token}) to remove any doubt about key values. And for better clarification findOne({"token":token}).